# C++ type trait to see if `static_cast<uint32_t>(k)` can be called on any variable of type `K`

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a type trait for detecting if, given a type `K`, I can call `static_cast` on variables of this type `K` (or reference to `K`) to `uint32_t` or not.

This is what I'm arriving at, but can't seem to make it work.

```
template <typename K, typename Whatever = void> struct ConvertibleToUint32 {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <typename K>
struct ConvertibleToUint32<K, decltype(static_cast<uint32_t>(std::declval<K>()))> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};
```

I have also tried using std::is_convertible, but doesn't seem to work here.

Here's a paste with a run - https://wandbox.org/permlink/iuP99PNAVIYhh208

The specialization doesn't seem to get hit.

Here's the full test program -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

    template <typename K, typename Whatever = void> struct ConvertibleToUint32 {
        static constexpr bool value = false;
    };

    template <typename K>
    struct ConvertibleToUint32<K, decltype(static_cast<uint32_t>(std::declval<K>()))> {
        static constexpr bool value = true;
    };


struct A {
    explicit operator uint32_t() const { return 1; }
};

struct B {
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << ConvertibleToUint32<A>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << ConvertibleToUint32<B>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_convertible<A, uint32_t>::value << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesen't get hit because `decltype(static_cast<uint32_t>(std::declval<K>()))` is not `void`, so it's not a more specialized version of the primary template for the argument `Whatever=void`.

The fix is fairly easy

```
template <typename K>
struct ConvertibleToUint32<K, decltype(static_cast<uint32_t>(std::declval<K>()), void())> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};
```

The second argument matches the default, and will therefore be picked up in partial ordering. Alternatively, you can just specify a default of `Whatever=uint32_t` and get the same effect. `void` is just what the general idiom employs.

```
template <typename K, typename Whatever = uint32_t>
struct ConvertibleToUint32 {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};
```

---

<sup><sub>As an aside, I suggest you start favoring the `cstdint` header and its `std::uint32_t` alias. Same net effect usually, but the use of the C++ version is generally preferable.</sub></sup>

Comment: Aha. I still have a hazy view of how partial ordering of specializations work, gotta read up in detail some time. But yeah, this works. Thanks!